# What is the use of RETURN statement in package specification

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, package

The code below compiles successfully. What i am wondering is what is the use of RETURN statement in the package specification. Is it a dead statement which will never run ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_pkg
IS
RETURN NUMBER;
END test_pkg;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg
IS
    PROCEDURE test_proc
    IS
    BEGIN
    NULL;
    END test_proc;
END test_pkg;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool, isn't it? `RETURN` - in this context - isn't a **statement**, but a **variable** whose datatype is `NUMBER`.

See an example:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_pkg
  2  IS
  3     RETURN  NUMBER;                   --> declared here
  4
  5     PROCEDURE test_proc;
  6  END test_pkg;
  7  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg
  2  IS
  3     PROCEDURE test_proc
  4     IS
  5     BEGIN
  6        test_pkg.return := 123;       --> used here
  7        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Return variable''s value = ' || test_pkg.return);
  8     END test_proc;
  9  END test_pkg;
 10  /

Package body created.

SQL> EXEC test_pkg.test_proc;
Return variable's value = 123

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```